Match RegEx except where preceded by character
I want to match a certain RegEx ABC except where an occurrence is preceded by a backtick.
So from this I want the first ABC but not the second.
Hello ABC `ABC

Using RegEx with negative lookahead:
(?!`)ABC

Both occurrences are matched:

Note, I don't want the backtick as part of the match so not this:
[^`]ABC

I would also like to match ABC when it is not preceded by any character at all i.e.
ABC `ABC

Should also match the first ABC

Try: (?<!\)ABC`

Negative look ahead?!

Yes, negative lookahead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Lookahead_assertion

@anubhava your answer works thanks! Would you care to post it officially perhaps with explanation?

I know what it is, but: which direction is the character you don't want to match, relative to the thing that you do? Also please note the [tag:regex] wiki.

A lookahead checks what follows a match ... you need a lookbehind which checks what precedes it.

@Marc: It appears it was just a typo moreover it might be a dupe also.


Try: (?<!`)ABC

As mentioned by anubhava, you should use negative look behind "(?<!`)ABC"
